# JPA Criteria filter collections based on condition

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, criteria, openjpa

Why Criteria query not filtering records based on **Services** (collection entities) condition **services.get("status"), "pending")** as below?

```
CriteriaQuery<Customer> query = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
    Root<Customer> customer = query.from(Customer.class);
Join<Customer, Service> services = customer.join("services", JoinType.INNER);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add(cb.equal(customer.get("customerId"), 1));
predicates.add(cb.equal(services.get("status"), "pending"));

query.select(customer).distinct(true)
        .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

List<Customer> customers = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

where as the SQL does filter records properly

```
  select * from customers c
  INNER JOIN SERVICES s on s.COID = c.COID 
  where c.ID=1 and
  s.status='pending';
```

Records were not qualified in resultset based on status condition(for collection), in fact, all services of a customer were returned.

I tried to use fetch Join (because there were 2 queries executed 1st for customer and 2nd for services of this customer, thought condition might be not evaluated in 2nd query) using

```
customer.fetch("services", JoinType.INNER);
```

but no luck.

I'm surprised by this behavior. I'm using OpenJPA JPA provider

Entities are **Customer** and **Service**.

```
 public class Customer{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer customerId;
    @OneToMany
    @MappedBy(name = "customer")
    private List<Service> services;
    }

 public class Service {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ServicesPK servicePK;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COID")
    private Customer customer;
    }

 @Embeddable
 @EqualsAndHashCode
 public class ServicesPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "COID")
    private Integer coId;
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    private Integer version;
}
```

Comment: @wypieprz  Could you please take a look at this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, change I did is I added type safety to the query.Know about type safety [typesafe](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/)

```
CriteriaQuery<Customer> query = cb.createQuery(Customer.class);
Root<Customer> customer = query.from(Customer.class);
Join<Customer, Service> services = customer.join(Customer_.services);
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

predicates.add(cb.equal(customer.get("customerId"), 1));
predicates.add(cb.equal(services.get(Service_.status), "pending"));

query.select(customer).distinct(true)
    .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

List<Customer> customers = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```